# Is there a ubuntu server menu-based network setup tool like during ubuntu install?

Tags: networking, command-line, server

During Ubuntu installation I enjoyed using the "Configure the Network" step:

[image]

I always assumed that there was some `dpkg-reconfigure` command that would re-run this, and that if I ever wanted to use it I would just need to search for it. However, when I actually went out and looked for a way to access something like this I couldn't find anything, and from what I've been reading it looks like there may be no such thing after all. Is that right?

To clarify, *I'm not having a trouble configuring my network adapter* (so no need for a response detailing how to accomplish that.) I'm just curious if Ubuntu server has a CLI menu-interface like the one that is used during installation - and if so, how does one access it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this menu-based interface is part of the installer, and does not exist independently. However, if and when Network Manager 0.9.10 comes to Ubuntu, you could use [`nmtui`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Networking_Config_Using_nmtui.html),  the text user interface for Network Manager for a nicer interface. Other options include [`wicd-cli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/wicd-cli.8.html), part of WICD, a network management program.

Comment: +1 - nice, i will check those out. good to know about the Network Manager 0.9.10.